# What are these square brackets in javascript imports in the MDN docs?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Was going through the MDN docs and found this page (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) about importing in javascript?

Very confused about the following lines, any help would be appreciated.

`import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";`

`import defaultExport, { export1 [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";`

Comment: `[]` in documentations typically means that that argument / paramater is optional - In this case, I would image it just means that you can keep repeating the `export2 as alias2` section

Comment: They indicate you can have unlimited list of parameters of given type.